# Get value form a label on submit a form

Tags: angularjs, forms, ionic2

hi i have a form with select data and a label which gets populated on page load i need that data to get added up along with the form data could someone help me

```
 <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="modifyMilkForm(form)" novalidate>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col style="text-align: right;">
                     <ion-label><b>Date :</b></ion-label>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col >
                     <ion-label><b>{{item.day}} / {{item.month}} / {{item.year}}</b></ion-label>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-row>
                <ion-col style="text-align: right;">
                     <ion-label><b>Brand Name :</b></ion-label>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-select name="selectedBrand" [(ngModel)]="selectedBrand" required>
                        <ion-option *ngFor="let brand of Brand;" [value]="brand.val">{{brand.name}}</ion-option>
                    </ion-select>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
</form>

modifyMilkForm(form){
        console.log("modified data", form.value);
    }
```

Comment: Pass item in your ngSubmit function and then you can retrieve the corresponding values that you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

in your submit function,

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="modifyMilkForm(item.day+'/'+item.month+'/' +item.year)" novalidate>
```

and in your **ts**,

```
modifyMilkForm(data){
    console.log("modified data", data);
}
```